# Extracting Sequence Unique to a Certain Genome

Tags: sequence-alignment, genome, mauve

I have two genomes with high similarity. But I found out that one genome has a longer sequence of about 200 kbp. I try to align the sequence with Mauve. How can I extract this unique 200 kbp?

Comment: How is this region demarcated? Between certain features? A separate contig?
How would you want the region identified for any such code to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer.

I've aligned these genomes (gbk files) with Mauve Contig Mover, and then I exported the Gap File into a csv file. Then I used python pandas to analyze the region that is unique to each strand from the csv file.